# Get command target using redis keyspace notifications

Tags: redis

When listening to Keyspace Notifications it looks like this:

```
 λ redis-cli --csv psubscribe '__keyspace@0__:myset:*'
Reading messages... (press Ctrl-C to quit)
"psubscribe","__keyspace@0__:myset:*",1
"pmessage","__keyspace@0__:myset:*","__keyspace@0__:myset:1","sadd"
"pmessage","__keyspace@0__:myset:*","__keyspace@0__:myset:1","srem"
```

The problem is that it never says the actual set key that is being added or removed. Is there any way to access the string that is being added or removed within a set via Keyspace Notifications? If it not possible is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The messages sent by the keyspace notifications mechanism do not include the actual data, only the key names.

You can make your own notifications just by calling [`PUBLISH`](http://redis.io/commands/publish) alongside the calls that modify the data - for atomicity consider using transactions or a Lua script.